# How to monitor SQL Restore on my web app

Tags: sql-server, monitoring, restore, jtds

I'm using a proc to manage my restore statements

```
...
EXEC('RESTORE DATABASE myDB FROM  DISK = N''C:\folder\myDB.bak'' WITH ...,  STATS = 10')
...
```

When I run this proc on MSSMS, I can see the % regularly.

I want to use this proc on my java web app with JTDS. Can I have this % as restore is processing ? Some restore take about 40 minutes, the user have to have a visual feedback on his restore.

Thx a lot

Comment: 40 minutes... check about `Instant File Initialization` - http://blog.devart.com/instant-file-initialization-killer-feature-for-sql-server.html

Comment: You can probably tie in to sql server extended events to get data about ongoing restores. Probably will require some code to do so. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630354%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Devart, it's good news that we can reduce backup time (we have 80go backup every day), thx for you'r blog. I will check it later, it's not my priority for the moment
N-West it seems to be what I expected, I will investigate. I'm new to SQL so I hope it's not soo hard. Thx

Comment: I found this (https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2343/how-to-monitor-backup-and-restore-progress-in-sql-server-2005-and-2008/) but it's for 2014 and N-West link for 2016, and we are on 2008 (on production) and 2012 (on pre-production)

Comment: Ok, my link is for 2005 and 2008, I tested it on 2008 and 2012, it works nicely.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way on https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2343/how-to-monitor-backup-and-restore-progress-in-sql-server-2005-and-2008/

```
SELECT session_id as SPID, command, a.text AS Query, start_time, percent_complete, dateadd(second,estimated_completion_time/1000, getdate()) as estimated_completion_time
FROM sys.dm_exec_requests r CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(r.sql_handle) a
WHERE r.command in ('BACKUP DATABASE','RESTORE DATABASE')
```